# How to control the processor frequency of i5 in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, intel-core-i5

On Ubuntu I can control the frequency of my CPU. I set it at the lowest value and then the fans are really quiet.

Is it possible to do it in Windows 7 ?

**EDIT**: The computer is a Laptop: Sony SVT 1311

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop PC?

Comment: It's a laptop, a Sony SVT 1311.

Answer (score 7):

Go to Control Panel -> Power Options and select `Power saver`

That should limit the processor to a set of lower powered CPU speeds.

Of course you can always adjust the settings of the `Power saver` plan to only ever use the minimal state by selecting `Edit Plan Settings` then `Change advanced power settings`.  On the window that opens look for `Processor power management` and set the `Maximum processor state` to 5% or something low.

On a laptop you should be able to get to the power options quickly by right clicking the battery icon in the bottom left of the task bar.

Comment: I already try it but it has no effect.

Comment: As I said on Ubuntu it seams to work, the processor is much quiet.

Comment: On some systems (like the Acer Aspire R7) the "Power Saver" mode is actually a bit of a lie at its defaults - the Maximum processor state is set to 100%. You have to manually go in and lower it. In addition, the best setting to lower it to is whatever your CPU jumps its voltage up in response to - so for example if it increases its voltage at 80%, you should set this to 80%. You have to do some digging to figure out what that would be. Sometimes this is in the Bios.

Answer (score 1):

I used to control CPU frequency settings in W7 using ASUS AI Suite, since I had ASUS mobo.
Look for similar software on the official site of your mobo manufacturer. This tool allowed either to change frequency or multiplier.

Besides, all new Intel Core i5 processors support Turbo Boost Technology,  which dynamically increases the processor's frequency as needed by taking advantage of thermal and power headroom to give you a burst of speed when you need it, and increased energy efficiency when you don’t.

Turbo Boost settings are controlled from within the BIOS.
Intel® Turbo Boost Technology is a processor technology and is operating system agnostic.

[Here you can read FAQ on this technology on Intel site.](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-029908.htm)

[Here are specs for 3rd generation of Core i5 CPU with Turbo Boost Tech.](http://ark.intel.com/compare/65510,69114,65509)

Comment: Yes I would like to desactivate the Turo Boost but my BIOS has almost zero options. Only change date, boot order and activate AT Technology (I guess Anti Theft). There is nothing about Turbo Boost. Is there any extended BIOS maybe? (I already updated it)

Answer (score 1):

Did You try speed fan for windows? It can monitor and control all sensors and fan speeds, and it's free, youcan download from [here](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php).

Comment: I tried it, without success. I set the core temp to 50/60C but it stays to 40/45. I can't change fan speed because speedfan didn't see them... (lists stays empty)

Answer (score 0):

Use [CPU Tweaker](http://www.tweakers.fr/cputweaker.html) to control CPU Frequency and Fan Speeds.